# Google GAE for PHP: same application, different deployments, different response times

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I have two identical app deployment - staging and production. However, response times on production 2x-6x slower.

Staging:
[image]

Production:
[image]

What may be the most obvious reasons for that?

Comment: Hmmm looks strange - can you share with me the two app_id's so I can take a look?

Comment: have you been testing your staging a lot more, thus keeping instances from needing to spin up? do you have a lot more live data in production causing queries to take longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I see happening is that sometimes you send a lot of requests simultaneously to the app.
What can happen, is that if your app doesn't have an instance running, it will start a new one - and the requests will sit in the pending queue waiting for the instance to start [does you app hit SQL? It might be spending time spinning up the cloud SQL instance on that first request]. Also, requests might be queued waiting for another request at the instance to complete before it can be processed.

On average, all of the requests process at the same speed on the production and staging server from what I can see, unless they are waiting for the instance to start or another request to finish.

You can see if a request is waiting for a free instance by looking at the 'pending_ms' value in the request logs. If this value is there it will be the number of milliseconds the request was queued for before being sent to an instance to process.

You can adjust the 'pending latency' sliders in the admin console to change how fast we create a new instance to handle pending requests.

We're also working hard at improving how we can parallelize multiple requests to a single instance.

Comment: Stuart, thank you for explaining this. I can now see described behavior in our logs.